# "What does so special he do?" or "What so special does he do?"?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

If he does some special things, what should the sentence look like?

> What **does** so special he **do**?

or

> What so special **does** he **do**?

or maybe

> **What's** so special he **does**?

Comment: "What does he do that is so special?"

Comment: None of your options are grammatical. There is no way in English to make _so special_ a noun phrase. It’s not possible. You have to do what @sdgluck suggests and make a relative clause.

Comment: The third example is very close to being OK.  "What is so special ***that*** he does?" - omitting "*that*" makes it miss the mark.

Comment: "What's so special about what he does?" is another alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that all of them are grammatically incorrect. The correct way of saying any of the above sentences would be:

1. > What is so special **that** he does?

   or
2. > What is so special **about** what he does?

   or
3. > What is so special **with** what he does?

You might want to consider any of the modifications given above for the same sentence you had a doubt with.